# Meteor: Accessing a website from the client with HTTP.get (CORS error)

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, client, cors

I can access the (secure) website without problems when I run the `HTTP.get` and `HTTP.post` commands from the server, using headers to identify myself via a cookie and with the required credentials. I'm using the HTTP package.

However I want the same to happen from the client itself. Here's the code on the client side:

```
HTTP.get('https://www.securewebsite.com/login1.php', {
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        // "DNT": "1",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6"
        // 'Accept-Charset' : 'utf-8',
        // "Cookie": cookie
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
       // some error handling code
    } else {
       // doing something with res
    }
});
```

I had to comment out the `Accept-Charset`, `DNT` and `cookie` headers as they were flagged as insecure. Error message eg for DNT: `Refused to set unsafe header "DNT"` (same for other headers)

However even then I get `OPTIONS` shown in the browser inspector (Chrome) and the following error message shows up:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.securewebsite.com/login1.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.`

Please note than `https://www.securewebsite.com/login1.php` is just an example, not the real website I'm calling. You can try `http://www.awest.de/` as a real example. As seen from the error message I'm currently calling it from local.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Am I missing some specific header? I've tried other URL's as well (including my own webspace) but I get the same error message, so it doesn't has anything to do with the URL I'm trying to GET from. It seems more a browser issue where it wants to stop some x-script execution (if I understand it correctly from what I read).

To explain why I want to access it from the browser: I don't want to violate the server's policy and thus requests should come from the clients IP-address and not my servers IP-address. I'm using two apps, one is just hosting the client side code and a second one is hosting only server side code.

Thanks for your help in advance, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with cors.
Try the headers inside php/js script (back-end/cors):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: Added: options = {
        timeout: timeoutMs,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, POST",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "X-Requested-With"
        }
    }; to it but I get the same error message from the preflight request

Comment: @a4xrbj1 What will happen if you clear any header inside `HTTP.get(`?

Comment: There is no difference if I put every header in a variable called options or I keep the object directly in the HTTP.get - the problem isn't the format.